# Как работает цикл while с функцией return в Java Script?

Tags: javascript

Объясните пожалуйста как работает данный код по-этапам:

```
function test(number)
{
 while(number<5){
   number++;
   }
   return number;
}
alert(test(2));
```

Почему в результате выводится 5?
Знаю, что цикл while повторяет блок кода,пока определенное условие является true. return используется для возвращения значения функции. 
Но что это значит в данном случае? Кто-нибудь может пожалуйста разложить по полочкам каждое действие для того,чтобы понять как мы получаем результат?

Comment: Цикл `while` работает до тех пор, пока `number` не станет равен 5. И только после этого он передаст управление последующему коду. `return` в любом случае выполнится только после завершения цикла, а в этом случае всегда `number == 5`

Comment: расставьте фигурные скобки правильно - return вне цикла